# Sorting an array of JSON objects: Should I use `json_decode` or `preg_match`?

Tags: php, json, performance, sorting

I have an array of json-encoded objects that I need to sort based on one of the properties every object has, using a custom comparison function passed to `usort`. The data looks something like this:

```
[
  '{"property-to-sort-by":"value1"}', 
  '{"property-to-sort-by":"value2"}',
  ...
]
```

There are two ways I can extract this property in the comparison function:

1. `json_decode` each object and compare the properties.
2. Use `preg_match` to extract the properties for comparison (one property per object).

Which is the more performant approach, or is there another approach I haven't thought of that would be even more performant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a potentially better way:

```
$array = json_decode("[".implode(",",$jsonArray)."]");
usort($jsonArray2, function($a, $b) {
    return strcasecmp($a->name, $b->name);
});
```

I did do some tests of this [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ec351608ecb9b9f424b767d47b168b531a331b08) but I'm still puzzled as to why this seems to be performing faster than the baseline.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR:** Given the need to only extract one property from each object, I found `preg_match` to be significantly more efficient than `json_decode` for sorting an array of json-encoded objects.

---

First I benchmarked the simplest comparison function I could imagine as a point of reference:

```
$s = microtime();
usort($jsonArray, function($a, $b) {
    return 1;
});
$p = microtime() - $s;
var_dump($p);
```

This trivial case sorted my test list in a little over .0002 microseconds. Here are my 10 trial times:

```
0.00022999999999995
0.00022800000000001
0.00022800000000001
0.00023300000000004
0.000217
0.00023899999999999
0.00021699999999999
0.00023000000000001
0.000251
0.00021499999999999
```

Next I benchmarked the `json_decode` approach:

```
$s = microtime();
usort($jsonArray, function($a, $b) {
    $aOrg = \json_decode( $a );
    $bOrg = \json_decode( $b );
    return strcasecmp($aOrg->name, $bOrg->name);
});
$p = microtime() - $s;
var_dump($p);
```

This function sorted my list in about 0.0008 or 0.0009 milliseconds:

```
0.00081499999999995
0.00096299999999999
0.000973
0.00081300000000001
0.00081299999999999
0.00084399999999996
0.000931
0.000875
0.000997
0.00081000000000009
```

Lastly, I tested the `preg_match` approach:

```
$s = microtime();
usort($jsonArray, function($a, $b) {
    preg_match('/"name":"(.+?)"/', $a, $aMatches);
    preg_match('/"name":"(.+?)"/', $b, $bMatches);
    $aName = $aMatches[1];
    $bName = $bMatches[1];
    return strcasecmp($aName, $bName);
});
$p = microtime() - $s;
var_dump($p);
```

This approach sorted my list in about 0.0004 milliseconds:

```
0.00047700000000001
0.000448
0.00044799999999995
0.00046199999999996
0.00045200000000001
0.00044999999999995
0.000448
0.000585
0.00045100000000001
0.000449
```

In summary, for my test list, sorting using `preg_match` added roughly a third less time to the sort operation than did using `json_decode`, compared to the trivial `return 1` implementation.

Comment: This is just not a fair comparison. Normally you'd do `json_decode` once before the sort. Doing `json_decode` within the sort callback means you'd be decoding on every comparison and there will be about O(*n* log*n*) comparisons. Also how do you end up with an array of json strings to begin with?

Comment: @apokryfos I store json objects in my database, so the array of json objects results from querying the database.